# Building a drag and drop factory layout web app

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, web-applications, drag-and-drop

I have experience using ZendFramework 2 (php) and some basic knowledge of Javascript and jQuery.

I need to build a web application where the user has a left bar with icons, he must be able to click them and drop them into a "draw zone" where he will create a topology of a factory with the different icons he drops from the bar and connect them with arrows of different lenghts.

I only need to know how to approach this. I think that the drag and drop feature can be implemented in jQuery as I found in some questions here, but how do I save the layout? How can I create that kind of arrows that are built when someone clicks on one point of the screen and moves the mouse towards another point and releases the click?. This kind of apps are made in Macromedia flash? or they can be made using pure Javascript and jQuery?

I´d appreciate any tutorial or reading material you can suggest me.

Answer (score 1):

@jahller is right -- you'll need advanced knowledge of JavaScript and a lot of time to implement what you want.  Although I don't think you need jQuery.

Or you can use a library to do most of what you want.  Here are some examples:

- [Flowchart](http://gojs.net/latest/samples/flowchart.html)
- [Page Flow](http://gojs.net/latest/samples/pageFlow.html)
- [Logic Circuit](http://gojs.net/latest/samples/logicCircuit.html)

Maybe you are trying to build something like [Process Flow](http://gojs.net/latest/samples/processFlow.html), although I don't know why that sample doesn't also include a Palette.

You might also be interested in some kind of monitoring display like [Shop Floor Monitor](http://gojs.net/latest/samples/shopFloorMonitor.html).

Disclosure: I have been implementing diagramming libraries for 20 years at Northwoods Software.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI with the drag and drop feature will probably not get you very far.

As you already said, it provides you with the drag and drop functionality, but it does not help with one of your biggest features: having arrows to connect the logical units. You should probably put some research into available JavaScript libraries for creating flow diagrams or entity relationship diagrams. Maybe there is something out there, which has enough functionality to provide you with all the features you need.

One quick Google search gave me this for example: https://github.com/apcj/arrows / http://www.apcjones.com/arrows/ This doesn't exactly provide what you are looking for, but could be a start.

Editing libraries like this is unfortunately a whole different topic. What you are aiming for could definitely require advanced knowledge of JavaScript.